# Azure Message Bus, Unable to complete a message

Tags: message-queue, azureservicebus

My project is a UWP application. I follow the guideline of this link. URL: https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/BasicSessionSendReceiveUsingQueueClient. Then I got a problem. The Message does not complete when I call 'session.CompleteAsync'. Message is still in queue until it runs out of its maximum delivery count.

```
    private async Task ProcessSessionMessagesAsync(IMessageSession session, Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var sessionId = session.SessionId;
        var sequenceNumber = message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber;
        var messageId = message.MessageId;
        var messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);

        await session.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }
```

Comment: Have you raised an issue with the development team in [the repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues)?

Comment: Is this every message or just intermittent?  If it is not every time, have you checked the cancellation token to see if a cancellation has been requested?